# Get File Name From FileStreamResult When Using Ajax/Axios?

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-core, axios, filestreamresult

I have in my asp.net core api controller

```
 return new FileStreamResult(excel, "application/ms-excel")
        {
            FileDownloadName = filename
        };
```

I am doing an ajax request to get this file

```
   var response = axios.get(
      `/endpoint`, {
        responseType: 'blob'
      });
```

then I am using a library called [download](https://github.com/rndme/download) which takes 3 parameters with one of them being "filename" and I am wondering if I can somehow get the filename that is coming from the server.

```
download(response.data,"test.xlsx", content);
```

Cors

```
 services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors",
       builder =>
       {
           builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
           .AllowAnyMethod()
           .AllowAnyHeader();
       }));
```

Answer (score 13):

First you need to expose `Content-Disposition` header in your CORS configuration since it's not included in [CORS-safelisted response headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers)

```
services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("Cors",
    builder =>
    {
        builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .WithExposedHeaders("Content-Disposition");
    }));
```

Then you should be able to parse response `Content-Disposition` header and get file name from it

```
axios.get(
    "/endpoint", {
        responseType: 'blob'
    })
    .then(response => {
        var contentDisposition = response.headers["content-disposition"];
        var match = contentDisposition.match(/filename\s*=\s*"(.+)"/i);
        var filename = match[1];
        console.log(filename);
    });
```

Comment: hmm I don't seem to have "content-disposition" header. just content-length, content-type.

Comment: @chobo2 are you performing cors request?

Comment: Yea a cors request is done before the actual request.

Comment: @chobo2 Okay, so you have to allow `Content-Disposition` header to be passed. It can be done via cors setup in your project. Please add code with your current `cors` settings I'll try to help with it

Comment: Ok I added Cors code from my startup.cs file but it already "allows all headers"

Comment: @chobo2 It's a bit different. I've updated my answer

Comment: @chobo2 Any luck with this?

Comment: Hey, did not see the update. I tried it and now the content-dispositon is being passed but the regex is not matching anything. Mine looks like: attachment; filename=CompanyName-CategoryName.xlsx; filename*=UTF-8''CompanyName-CategoryNames.xlsx

Comment: @chobo2 This is very surpising for me because I got response with double quotes for `filename`. Please try this regex `/filename\s*=\s*(.+);/i`

Comment: I'd suggest the regex to be `filename\s*=\s*"?(.+)"?;` to support optional quotation marks. Either with or without quotation mars would be valid.

Comment: This answer should be marked as Accepted. I had the exact same question as the OP, and this answer provided everything to make it work.